# Suppress Spark Java API warnings

Tags: java, apache-spark, logging

I am using Spark Java API in my thesis project. Since I need to print a lot of results in the console, I am trying to suppress all spark related INFO logging. I am working the project both locally (for debugging etc.) and remotely on a cluster. I managed to turn off most of them using the below sample configuration.

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local[16]");
final JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

ctx.setLogLevel("ERROR");
```

However, I am still getting WARNINGS every time I initialize a spark context, which can be disorienting at times. Below I am giving a sample of the console output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/Users/SKIKK/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-unsafe_2.12/3.2.2/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

I tried different suggestions in the forum; however, I was unable to find a working solution.

Comment: The warning isn't coming from spark or the logger, but directly from the JVM. It is directly printed to the console and does not use a logger. Thus, reconfiguring the logger won't help.

Comment: I see, did not think about that since it was printed only when I was using spark.

Comment: The "proper way" would be to fix the reflective behaviour in spark. There is [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34095) that seems to be exactly what you observe.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660419/apache-spark-running-with-warnings-with-illegal-reflective-access-by-org-apache) it is suggested to run with Java 8, to avoid these messeges. However, [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-illegal-reflective-access) states that "Since Java 17, the –illegal-access option is entirely removed.". I am using Java 11. I will try and run the project with a different version of Java and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660419/apache-spark-running-with-warnings-with-illegal-reflective-access-by-org-apache) it is suggested to run with Java 8, to avoid these messeges. However, [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-illegal-reflective-access) states that "Since Java 17, the –illegal-access option is entirely removed".

I switched to Java 17. The below line did the magic:
`Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.toLevel("ERROR"));`